# Error with MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I impored MySQLdb to use in python but i am getting the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 76, in <module>
    db = Database()
  File "test.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = self.host, user = self.user, passwd = self.passwd, db = self.db)
  File "/home/ue/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ue/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Exception AttributeError: "Database instance has no attribute 'connection'" in <bound method Database.__del__ of <__main__.Database instance at 0xb74cf80c>> ignored
```

I have seen other posts but none of them is helping me. I can even restart mysql as I cannot find `/var/run/mysqld/`

I do not think there is an error in the code as it is from Mike Hibberts Python video lectures: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFdNteScYe4&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xm1yUDAh2_pXGWBTePjCa3n

Would really really appreciate help in this.

Comment: You "don't think there is an error in the code", well can we confirm that? I mean as is all anyone can say is that there is an issue on line 76 of `test.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use some msyql client to check your mysql database first. #2002 error means it can not connect to mysql, I have confront this cause I have not start mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

@Lego Stormtroopr

I have added my code here. Sorry abt that, I should not assume that.

```
import MySQLdb

class Database:
host = "localhost"
user = "testuser"
passwd = "testpass"
db = "test"

def __init__(self):
    self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = self.host, user = self.user, passwd = self.passwd, db = self.db)
def query(self, q):
    cursor = self.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute(q)
    self.connection.commit()
    return cursor.fetchall()

def __del__(self):
    self.connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

db = Database()

q = "DELETE FROM testTable"

db.query(q)

q = """
INSERT INTO testTable
('name', 'age')
VALUES
('Mike', 39),
('Michael', 32),
('Angela', 21)
"""
db.query(q)

q = """
SELECT * FROM testTable
WHERE age = 21
"""
people = db.query(q)

for person in people:
    print "Found: %s" % person['name']
```